# Font family choice in rich text

Tags: richtext

Is there a way to choose the font family in rich text field? I want to have the option to choose from 2 or 3 font families in the rich text field. Is that possible in craft?

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the RTE you're using and what kind of features it supports. With the default Redactor, it should be possible via the configs in craft/config/redactor/ folder.
Peronally I don't think a content-editor should have that ability. This should be handled with classes or different fields/elements. They can really mess up your site.

Comment: Redactor `formattingAdd` config can be used to add css classes to paragraphs. https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/formatting-add/